# Send meeting update on Custom Event VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, apex-email-service, event, custom

I am currently using a custom vf page for Event object. I was able to send email notification to invitees but i can't send an meeting update to the same invitees.

I am using this code to send the update. This works on Database.Insert for sending new/initial meeting request.

```
List<EventRelation> evtUpdate = new List<EventRelation>();
                Database.DMLOptions dlo = new Database.DMLOptions();
                dlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail  = true; //User inside organization Emails
                dlo.EmailHeader.triggerOtherEmail  = true; //Outside Emails
                dlo.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = false;

            //  system.debug('@' + evtUpdate);
                for(EventRelation evtRelObj : [Select Id from EventRelation where isInvitee= true AND EventId =: evt.Id] ){
                 system.debug('updatecheck' + evtRelObj);
                 evtRelObj.setOptions(dlo);
                 evtUpdate.add(evtRelObj);
             } 

                Database.update(evtUpdate,dlo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [DMLOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm):

```
Database.DMLOptions dmlOptions = new Database.DMLOptions(); 
dmlOptions.EmailHeader.TriggerUserEmail = TRUE; 
Database.update(evtUpdate, dmlOptions);
```

Refer [Setting DML Options](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database_dmloptions.htm) as well.

Comment: I used that on my code above , it seems there's a bug on the Update part. We used a work around of deleting the event relation ids then reinserting it so attachments for the events can be updated and sent   Thank you for your response!